# Make old wordpress theme work in new wordpress version

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a client with a Wordpress site we built about five years ago in Wordpress 3.1. We used a theme that ended up never being updated by the creator. I have heavily customized it but I'm wondering if there are some things I can do to make the theme compatible with a newer version of Wordpress (especially the more sophisticated navigation functionality available). The client can't afford the hours it would take to build or customize another theme. If it's possible to update the theme, I would do it for them no charge as I'd like to learn.

Possibly important to know - at the time, I was a front-end developer just learning Wordpress, so I did not use a child theme (oh, believe me -- you can't say anything I haven't said to myself).

I have searched quite a bit on here and on the web.  I've not found anything specific to editing a theme for compatibility with later Wordpress versions.

Thanks in advance.

Tonya

Comment: Its not an question. If you would like to integrate old WordPress themes, check the WordPress-Codex and change old methods.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin looks like it will solve your needs:

[**WordPress.com Theme Updater**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpresscom-theme-updates/)

"*Your WordPress.com themes might need updating, but who wants to update them manually? This plugin enables seamless updating of your WordPress.com themes right in the WordPress updater, no fuss, no muss, even on multisite networks.*"